# Apache Kafka - Uneven load across disks and brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 2x broker Kafka setup running on EC2, each with 4x4GB GP2 SSDs, the topic has 6 partitions and 1 replica. They drives mounted and I have set them up in the server.properties. But when I was load testing my system and seeing what was happening with the drives, 1 of the 4 drive on broker 1 had a had stored a lot of the data, eg of what I got:

Broker 1: ** NOTE: I manually reproduced the figures for mount /a for the post ***

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G   12K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  344K  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.3G  6.1G  17% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdg       3.9G  8.0M  3.6G   1% /b
/dev/xvdf       3.9G  600M  3.2G   17% /a
/dev/xvdh       3.9G  8.0M  3.6G   1% /c
/dev/xvdi       3.9G  8.0M  3.6G   1% /d
```

Broker 2:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G   12K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  344K  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.3G  6.1G  17% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdg       3.9G  8.0M  3.6G   1% /b
/dev/xvdf       3.9G  8.0M  3.6G   1% /a
/dev/xvdh       3.9G  8.0M  3.6G   1% /c
/dev/xvdi       3.9G  8.0M  3.6G   1% /d
```

Can someone explain what is happening and if I have set something up wrong? I thought they were supposed to be approx even across all drives?

Comment: It seems topic replication is not happening. Can you check whether you configure `multi-broker Kafka setup` properly like they both are pointing to same `zookeeper`?

Comment: Here is the gist with the config files for ZK and Kafka (broker 0): https://gist.github.com/nateuni/4bb9d8f928fed5935dda59a70b2c468e

Comment: And yes they are both pointing to the same zookeeper!

Comment: Configuration looking good. I suspect producer might be sending to only 1 partition! would you mind to check  and post results of `describe` command on respective topic?

Comment: That looks ok as well: https://gist.github.com/nateuni/71ecc7c0db0808ab3847abd0db38771a

Comment: Oh my bad! I'm sorry! I would have asked you result of following command `bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --time -1 --topic test_topic` which gives you latest offsets of each partition of topic `test_topic`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111752/discussion-between-avr-and-nate-uni).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you send load over Kafka, the producer uses a [Partitioner](http://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) implementation over the set of keys being sent, in order to work out which partition to write the message into. The default Partitioner implementation uses a hashing function. If you send all of your messages with the same key, then they will all hash into the same partition. The same can be true of a small set of keys - hashing often produces uneven distributions.

Your best bet is to use a larger key set, or configure the producer with a Partitioner that performs a more even distribution of messages - via round-robin for example. Whether this is something you want to do depends on whether you have a requirement to ensure that some messages are processed in order, in which case you should ensure that related messages use the same key, and take this into account in your Partitioner.

Comment: I love you, no seriously, I do. This topic is so broad and in the pipeline that I am creating, I didn't understand that it was the producers job to split over the partitions. So I went to look in rsyslog and of course there are options to do exactly that! Thanks for answer the question that no one else did in IRC!

Comment: No worries. If you want a high-level overview of the Kafka internals and tradeoffs, I did a conference presentation on it comparing it to regular messaging concepts - https://vimeo.com/163887131